# Is there any way to receive a data from the server and fill the html tags(like textbox) with that data except the use of xml ?? If yes ,then how?

Tags: javascript, html, cgi

I am trying to receive data from the server. I am using appweb web server. I am storing data into a text file using a CGI Script. I am restricted to use only HTML and JavaScript at the client-side. I have one text file named test.txt, the contents of the test.txt are something like this: Hello,world. This text file resides on the server-side.

My HTML file needs to have two textboxes named t1 and t2. What I wanted is to fill that text boxes t1 and t2 with the values ‘Hello’ and ‘world’ respectively. How can I do this without XML?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need XML? What you need is AJAX technique, which, while it does include XML (X) in its name, actually doesn't have anything to do with XML. It will be much easier if you include jQuery or another library, though, dealing with Ajax is painful if you do it manually.

Comment: Please post the JavaScript code that's storing the text: the SO crystal ball is in the repair shop this week.

Answer (score 1):

In the `<body>` `onload` event, make an AJAX request to the file. When received split it and put the result in your text boxes.

Like Amadan says in his comment, while the X in AJAX stands for XML, the request can be used to get any kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the code, so this is just a wild-ass guess:

you might want to tell AJAX how to interpret and store the response data, either as responseText or as responseXml. It could be that you are telling AJAX to store responseXml. Please try using responseText instead if so.